# Why the error if semicolon not available?

Tags: javascript, iife

It is a very simple IIFE situation in JavaScript.
But the semicolon at the end of the first line will make a huge difference whether it is over there or not.

Here is the error version and no semicolon in the first line:

```
const obj = {}
(function () { })()
```

And Chrome complains that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: {} is not a function
```

How does browser read this code?

If we add semicolon at the end of that line, error dismissed:

```
const obj = {};
(function () { })()
```

I was told that semicolon is not necessary in JavaScript but it apparently is wrong in this situation. Why?

Comment: The semicolon _is_ necessary in JavaScript, [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion) can't do all of them.

Comment: Javascript is a interesting language

Comment: Characters at the beginning  ; ! - ~ + of an iife fools the browser to think it's an expression instead of a function when parsed.

Comment: @PrinceAgrawal Javascript is an "interesting" language in the same sense that we live in "interesting" times.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolons in JavaScript are optional, but sometimes missing semicolon can produce error.

In your case, the `const obj = {}` can be in multiline as well as follow:

```
const obj = {
}
```

So, javascript doesn't actually knows when your executional statement has been ended or not. As a result, javascript considers `const obj = {} (function() {})()` as a single statement, which produces error.
Whereas, when you put a semicolon, you explicitly specifies that the statement ended here, hence `const obj = {}` and `(function() {})()` as a separate statements.

This is also discussed at https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi

Comment: Strictly speaking semi-colons are not optional. ASI is an error-correction procedure to correct poor code.

Answer (score 0):

From ECMAScript® Language Specification:

[12.9.3.1 Interesting Cases of Automatic Semicolon Insertion in Statement Lists](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-asi-interesting-cases-in-statement-lists)

> In a *StatementList*, many *StatementListItems* end in semicolons,
> which may be omitted using automatic semicolon insertion. As a
> consequence of the rules above, at the end of a line ending an
> expression, a semicolon is required if the following line begins with
> any of the following:
>
> - **An opening parenthesis** ((). Without a semicolon, the two lines together are treated as a *CallExpression*.
> - **An opening square bracket** ([). Without a semicolon, the two lines together are treated as property access, rather than an
>   *ArrayLiteral* or *ArrayAssignmentPattern*.
> - **A template literal** (`). Without a semicolon, the two lines together are interpreted as a tagged Template (13.3.11), with the
>   previous expression as the *MemberExpression*.
> - **Unary + or -**. Without a semicolon, the two lines together are interpreted as a usage of the corresponding binary operator.
> - **A RegExp literal**. Without a semicolon, the two lines together may be parsed instead as the / *MultiplicativeOperator*, for example
>   if the RegExp has flags.